# cocoapod without using any repos

Tags: git, frameworks, cocoapods

I am building a new library in my machine which I want to distribute to my customers as SDK, to make this I used **Cocoapod Packager**.. After building this now I think can any cocoapod be built without using any repos like as I don't to push any files to any repository and after the cocoapod packager finished building .framework, i will handover that to my customer. This will facilitate me not to use any private repos (which involves money) and that makes my code secure too.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Hi all I figured that out in elder days, it can be used using "local" key word... however when I am trying to use now, its not working. I tried searching in many places, some says to use "dependency" now my questions is if I put a project in "dependency" with path/podspec, will the files with dependency pod spec does not get pushed to repos

Comment: My only concern is to prevent the files in dependency pod spec to be pushed to repos...